# How to use component without npm. I use Vue from CDN

Tags: vue.js

I want to use [vue-good-table](https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/) but I use Vue from CDN so I can't do this like it's described in the documentation. I probably can import this library using:

https://unpkg.com/vue-good-table@2.16.2/dist/vue-good-table.cjs.js

but how to load this component in

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#my-table',
  ....
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try this, but have you looked at adding a script tag with [`dist/vue-good-table.js`](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/blob/master/dist/vue-good-table.js) ? Then I would expect you need to do this:

```
Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
```

like any other Vue plugin.

Comment: thanks, I did it and got ReferenceError: exports is not defined - https://unpkg.com/vue-good-table@2.16.2/dist/vue-good-table.cjs.js :10

Comment: Are you sure you took the ".js" version and not the ".cjs.js" ?

Answer (score 0):

To use [vue-good-table](https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/) in this way, you can reference it using

`window['vue-good-table'].VueGoodTable`

For example:

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#my-table',
  components: {
    VueGoodTable: window['vue-good-table'].VueGoodTable
  },
  ....
```